# Creating a C++ object with and without new keyword

Tags: c++, class, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation, copy-constructor

Creating an object with new keyword:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
  private:
  string name;

  public:
  Person(string name) {
    setName(name);
  }

  string getName() {
    return this->name;
  }

  void setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
  }
};

int main() {
  Person *person1 = new Person("Rajat");
  Person *person2 = person1;

  person2->setName("Karan");

  cout << person1->getName() << endl;
  cout << person2->getName() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Karan  
Karan
```

Creating an object without new keyword:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
  private:
  string name;

  public:
  Person(string name) {
    setName(name);
  }

  string getName() {
    return this->name;
  }

  void setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
  }
};

int main() {
  Person person1("Rajat");
  Person person2 = person1;

  person2.setName("Karan");

  cout << person1.getName() << endl;
  cout << person2.getName() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Rajat  
Karan
```

I expected the output to be 'Karan Karan' as I thought in `Person person2 = person1`, `person2` refers to the same `person1`. But it isn't the case.

Can someone please explain what does the line `Person person2 = person1` do under the hood? Does it create a totally new object?

Comment: Great question as you've highlighted what seems to be a very important misconception that newbies have about C++. `Person person2 = person1;` **copies** a person object. It's absolutely not the case that person1 and person2 refer to the same object. They are distinct (but equal) objects. I do find it surprising that so many newbies assume the opposite. There's no basis for that assumption that I can think of, except maybe experience with other languages.

Comment: If you can get crystal clear the difference between copying a reference and copying a value then you'll overcome many of the problems that newbies have in understanding C++.

Comment: @john-I am also new to C++ and am from Java background so was confused a bit. and thank you for appreciating my question :)

Comment: @john - It's probably fairer to say that it is a misconception that newbies have about C++ when they have previously learned some other languages. I've encountered a fair few people learning C++ as their *first* language, and none of them have ever had such a misconception. Some other languages like Java, Eiffel (the list goes on) default to reference semantics, and I've yet to encounter a person with the "misconception" about C++ who doesn't have a background in one of those languages, and simply assumed without checking that C++ would work as their previously learned language(s)

Comment: @Peter I'm basing my opinion on the questions I see here, and unfortunately newbies don't normally explain themselves, but I think the misconception is commoner than you're suggesting. I'm not saying that newbies have a coherent understanding that just happens to be wrong (but Karan seems to be an exception to that) but rather that they get confused about what copying actually means, is a value or is it a reference. Often newbies have no consistent thinking about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what's going on in the background.

**First case**

- While using `new` keyword, `new` created an object and returned a pointer to that object.

  ```
                             +--------------------------+
         person1 ----------> |    Person Object         |
                             |        name = Rajat      |
                             +--------------------------+
  ```
- You then copied ***the address*** to the object in another pointer to object. So basically now both pointers point to the same object.

  ```
                             +--------------------------+
         person1 ----------> |    Person Object         |
                             |        name = Rajat      |
         person2-----------> |                          |
                             +--------------------------+
  ```
- Now, You then changed the value of `name` using one pointer and changing the value using one pointer changed both `person1` and `person2`.

```
person2->setName("Karan")
```

```
                               +--------------------------+
           person1 ----------> |    Person Object         |
                               |        name = Karan      |
           person2-----------> |                          |
                               +--------------------------+
```

*Is it so??*

**No!** Basically it changed for only the object it points. Hence for one object. In fact, there were never two objects, two objects never got created. It was the same object pointed by two pointers.

**In second case**

- You created an object and that object (not a pointer to the object) and stored in variable `person1`.

  ```
                             +--------------------------+
                             | Person Object (Person 1) |
                             |        name = Karan      |
                             |                          |
                             +--------------------------+
  ```
- Now, when you assigned `person2 = person1`, there is something called **Copy constructor** is involved here.
- It creates another object for `person2` copying everything in `person1` to `person2`.

  ```
                             +--------------------------+
                             | Person Object (Person1)  |
                             |        name = Rajat      |
                             |                          |
                             +--------------------------+

                             +--------------------------+
                             | Person Object (Person2)  |
                             |        name = Rajat      |
                             |                          |
                             +--------------------------+
  ```

Hence, here we have two *independent* objects.

- When you changed the value for one, the value got changed for only one, for the ones you actually wanted to change. And another independent object is as it was earlier.

  ```
                             +--------------------------+
                             | Person Object (Person1)  |
                             |        name = Rajat      |
                             |                          |
                             +--------------------------+

                             +--------------------------+
                             | Person Object (Person2)  |
                             |        name = Karan      |
                             |                          |
                             +--------------------------+
  ```

Comment: The fact that C++ gives you this choice is one of it's strengths, but also why it's more complex than other languages we could mention.

Comment: True that @john :) ^-^

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, you have two pointers pointing two the same object which is dangerous, hence on using any of the two pointers to make a change you change the same object. Note that you have created only one object.

```
Person *person2 = person1;
```

The previous line creates a new pointer pointing to the same object pointed to by the pointer `person1`

While in the second snippet you have created `person2` object which is different from `person1` but has the same value for `name` data member (because you've used the copy ctor) and then you have changed the value of the `name` of `person2`, hence two different names.

```
Person person2 = person1;
```

The previous line creates a new object using copy actor, hence have the same values for the data members.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you have pointers to `Person` which actually pointing to the same dynamically allocated object. Two pointers but there are no two separate objects. Therefore, changing the name will affect both.

In the second one, you do *[copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)* and has created literally two distinct objects here.

```
Person person2 = person1;
```

Therefore you have different names after setting them.